# Colouring and shading/texture of bars according to grouping ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a bar plot like where, as with the example data and script below, a measurement is taken from 4 individuals say before and after giving a treatment. Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to upload an example picture.

I would like to plot the individuals by a certain colour (e.g. Tom as green, Fred red, etc) but then for the bars representing the treatment I would like to add diagonal lines on top of the colour to indicate treatment.

Is this possible easily? The code below I have adapted from: [Generate ggplot2 boxplot with different colours for multiple groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026215/generate-ggplot2-boxplot-with-different-colours-for-multiple-groups)

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions. I hope what I'd like to do makes sense.

Example data (sorry, not sure how to upload it so imported from .csv):

```
Name,Time,Dose,Variable,n,Mean,SD,Median,Upper.SEM,Lower.SEM
Ted,1,0,P,3,20.1341,1.049791,20,0.5728394,0.5569923
Fred,1,0,P,3,38.63702,1.042969,37.74,0.9499892,0.9271918
Tom,6,0,P,3,42.3231,1.073583,43.75,1.7710033,1.6998725
Peter,6,0,P,3,36.01035,1.208213,35.63,4.1551262,3.7252776
Ted,1,1,P,3,22.79528,1.110182,21.64,1.4179833,1.334943
Fred,1,1,P,3,24.25966,1.156925,23.82,2.1300073,1.9580866
Tom,6,1,P,3,13.78995,1.170568,13.15,1.3126463,1.1985573
Peter,6,1,P,3,23.3236,1.4403,20.65,5.4688355,4.4300848
```

And code I have been using:

```
g<- ggplot(example, aes(x=Name, y=Mean,fill=interaction(Name,Dose) ))
g<-g + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") 
g<-g + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Mean+Upper.SEM, ymin=Mean-Lower.SEM),       position=position_dodge(0.9), width=0.5)
g<- g+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("green","green","red","red","green","green","red","red"
                    ))
g
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I saw the answer there but thought maybe there'd been an update since. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to use textures, and as the link in @Henrik's comment explains, that's not possible in `ggplot`. One possible work-around is to use different colors for the names, and different shades of color for the doses.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
categories         <- aggregate(Dose~Name,example,function(x)length(unique(x)))  # number of sub-category for each category
category.palettes  <- c("Purples","Reds","Greens","Blues")
colors <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(categories),
                        function(i){colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,category.palettes[i])[3:7])(categories[i,2])}))
names <- sort(unique(example$Name))

g <- ggplot(example, aes(x=Name, y=Mean,fill=interaction(Dose,Name) ))
g <- g + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") 
g <- g + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Mean+Upper.SEM, ymin=Mean-Lower.SEM), position=position_dodge(0.9), width=0.5)
g <- g+ scale_fill_manual("Subject", values=colors, breaks=paste0("1.",names),labels=names)
g
```

Comment: Hi jlhoward, thank you very much. This is alternative works really well for me too. Just one more question- is it possible for the key to include all colours used so that we can see light purple is control Fred and dark purple is treated Fred etc? I found something here [link](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs) which I have manage to fiddle with and get the desired result. However it's quite fiddly and wondered if there is an easier way of doing this? Let me know if you need me to upload what I have done by adapting the code in the link.

Comment: Take out the `breaks=paste0("1.",names),labels=names` arguments to `scale_fill_manual(...)`.