# Differently colored grouped bar plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a barplot with two factors and I need every bar to be in a different color.  So far, I use one of the factors as the fill aesthetic:  
`ggplot(valenz, aes(x=group, y=mean, fill = condition))`

Below is one example with fake data of how my barplots looks.

[image]

What I need is that **color also differs depending on the group, not only the condition**, e.g.:  
group b, condition 1: light blue  
group b, condition 2: dark blue  
group c, condition 1: light green  
group c, condition 2: dark green and so on...  
So, using the 'alpha' option doesn't seem to do it.  
Below is what the plot should approx. look like.

[image]

The rest should stay exactly how it is right now.  
Does anyone know how to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps something akin to `aes(group, mean, fill = group, alpha = condition)`?

Comment: *fake data of how my barplots looks* ... isn't that the desired look per your description below?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas! Actually, I tried the 'alpha' option but I need the bars to really have different colors depending on their group, not just different amounts of transparency...

Comment: This is a duplicate, but the question has been incorrectly flagged. I think you can find your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435979/colouring-and-shading-texture-of-bars-according-to-grouping-ggplot2

Comment: @MikeyHarper that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think this might help you move in the right direction :

```
library(tidyverse)

valenz <- data.frame(
  mean = c(6, 0, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5),
  group = c("group a","group a", "group b","group b", "group c","group c","group d","group d"),
  condition = c("condition1", "condition2","condition1", "condition2","condition1", "condition2","condition1", "condition2")

)

ggplot (valenz, aes(x=group, y=mean, fill=factor(condition), alpha=group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

source: [R ggplot barplot; Fill based on two separate variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170656/r-ggplot-barplot-fill-based-on-two-separate-variables) and some of my own tweaks.

[image: Link_To_generated_Image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19354395)

Comment: Oh ok thank you! I'm a new to Stack, will keep that in mind!

Comment: Don't worry, it happens all the time. Note where it says to include the relevant parts of the answer. It's good to have new users, good luck.

Comment: Thank you! Just made the changes, I hope this is better :)

Comment: Yes, it is. The thing that was now missing was code formating: you must put 4 spaces before each code line. To do this you can select the code and press Ctrl+K or use the foramting tools on top of the edit area.

Comment: Wow okay! Thanks again. Still learning as I go

Comment: Thank you, Anurag! I've already tried the 'alpha' option but I need the bars to really have different colors depending on their group, not just different amounts of transparency.