# fill Interaction not working with ggplot2 and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I want to add interaction to the fill argument of my plotly figure, as e.g. answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026215/generate-ggplot2-boxplot-with-different-colours-for-multiple-groups).

However, although the ggplot figure comes out correctly, the plotly does not. I am using the following versions and show a MWE below:

`ggplot2`: version `2.0.0.9000`, `plotly`: version `2.0.19`

```
library(plotly)
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = interaction(factor(cyl),carb))) + geom_boxplot()
(gg <- ggplotly(g))
```

Any ideas why g and gg differs above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete solution. Include the interaction to your `x` term:

```
# use lex.order to obtain correct ordered levels
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T), y = mpg,fill = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T))) + 
     geom_boxplot()
# check the plot
a
# plotly
ggplotly(a)
```

Comment: any ideas on fixing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493789/how-to-change-the-position-of-plotly-figures-using-ggplotly) problem?

Answer (score 1):

actually there is an alternative that will give you exactly what you want.

```
mtcars$intec <- interaction(factor(cyl),carb)

mtcars %>%
  plot_ly(x = cyl, y = mpg, type = "box", color = as.factor(intec), fill=as.factor(intec)) %>%
  layout(boxmode = "group")
```

[image]