# How to change the position of plotly figures using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to remove the legend title using ggplotly without success. I'm sure there is an easy fix, but I cannot find the documentation for it - and removing the legend title (or changing the positioning) using ggplot fails to work. See e.g.:

```
# Creating the ggplot:
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T), 
y = mpg,fill = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T))) + 
      geom_boxplot() + theme(legend.title=element_blank())
    a # No Legend Title
    # plotly puts back the legend title
    ggplotly(a)
```

Any ideas how to change / remove the title of the graph? Should it be done using ggplotly or ggplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `labs` function:

```
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T), 
y = mpg,fill = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T))) + 
      geom_boxplot()
# update the legend
a <- a + labs(fill= "New Legend")
a
# to remove the label and update the axis texts use:
a <- a+labs(fill= "",x="Cyc/Carb",y="Miles/(US) gallon")
ggplotly(a)
```

Comment: Works thanks! I had both a fill and colour call, which should both be set to "": labs(colour = "", fill = "")