# How to create a ggplot2 with both stacked and dodged bars (3 variables) in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a ggplot with bars that are stacked (agreement adding up to 1.0 or 100%) but evaluated over time (x-axis shows time) and for 3 different categories (e.g. types of car). Here is some sample data:

```
Year <- c(rep(2012, 9), rep(2013, 9), rep(2014, 9))
Car <- rep(c(rep("A", 3), rep("B",3), rep("C",3)),3)
FuelEfficient <- rep(c("Agree", "Neither", "Disagree"),9)
Perception <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2)
df <- data.frame(Year, Car, FuelEfficient, Perception)
```

I am imagining that the cars would each have their own colour, and would appear next to each other at each time point. Each car would then be composed of a bar with 3 different shades of the same colour (representing agreement/disagreement/neither), adding up to 1.0 or 100%.
[see image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT3zV.jpg)

I currently have this code:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Year, y=Perception, fill=interaction(FuelEfficient,Car), dodge=Car))+
geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values=rev(c("#d95f02", "#fc8d62", "#ffb79c", "#7570b3", "#8da0cb", "#b7c7ed", "#1b9e77", "#66c2a5", "#bff5e4")))
```

which is basically stacking the 3 car types on top of each other at each time point [see image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7KXS.jpg). This makes it easy to compare trends for each car over time, but not to compare the cars to one another, since each car is at its own level. I had hoped that dodge=Car (present in my code and used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026215/generate-ggplot2-boxplot-with-different-colours-for-multiple-groups)) would solve this problem, but it makes no difference.

[This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge) could be going in the right direction:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(x_label = factor(str_replace(interaction(Year, Car), '\\.', ' / '),
                      ordered = T))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x_label, y=Perception, fill=FuelEfficient)) +
geom_bar(stat='identity') +
scale_fill_manual(values=rev(c("#d95f02", "#fc8d62", "#ffb79c", "#7570b3", "#8da0cb", "#b7c7ed", "#1b9e77", "#66c2a5", "#bff5e4")))
```

but I would still like to assign different colours to cars A,B,C.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible options:

Add `, width = 1` to the `geom_bar` if you want no gap between each bar within each facet.)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

Year <- c(rep(2012, 9), rep(2013, 9), rep(2014, 9))
Car <- rep(c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3)), 3)
FuelEfficient <- rep(c("Agree", "Neither", "Disagree"), 9)
Perception <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2)
df <- data.frame(Year, Car, FuelEfficient, Perception)

# Concatenate option
ggplot(df, aes(str_c(Year, " | ", Car), Perception, fill = interaction(FuelEfficient, Car))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(c("#d95f02", "#fc8d62", "#ffb79c", "#7570b3", 
                                   "#8da0cb", "#b7c7ed", "#1b9e77", "#66c2a5", "#bff5e4"))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Year & Car", fill = "Car Fuel\nEfficiency")
```

[image]

```r
# Facet option
ggplot(df, aes(Car, Perception, fill = interaction(FuelEfficient, Car))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ Year) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(c("#d95f02", "#fc8d62", "#ffb79c", "#7570b3", 
                                   "#8da0cb", "#b7c7ed", "#1b9e77", "#66c2a5", "#bff5e4"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_percent()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Year & Car", fill = "Car Fuel\nEfficiency")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>